# Python, storing 2 different user inputs into 2 variables, compare those 2 user inputs against 2 access lists

Tags: python, variables, indexing

I'm new at this. I want to take a username and device id as 2 separate USER inputs stored in variables.

I tried indexing both of the access lists. I would check the user input and device id inputs against the access lists. The indexing of the lists is necessary, I think, because if I entered 'Chad' as the user and '127' (both at index 0) as the device id, it would be fine. If I entered 'Chad' as the user and '416' (index 0 and index 1) as the device id, that would allow it too.

I need to check the inputs against the access lists as long as the inputs are at the exact same indices in the list.

The problem: If a correct username is entered, access is granted, if any of the device id's are entered it grants access also, which I do not want.

Code snippet below:

```
approved_users = ['Chad', 'Tina', 'Jared', 'Lars', 'Henry', 'Jasmine']
device_id = [127, 416, 709, 358, 672, 939]
user = input('Enter your username: ')
device = input('Enter your device id: ')
au = approved_users.index(user)
di = device_id.index(device)
if user in approved_users and device in device_id and au == di:
    print(user, "has access to the system with a device id of:", device)
else:
    print(user, "with device id:", device, "is not in the system, entered an invalid id, or both")
```

I tried indexing the access lists and then comparing the user inputs against them to see if the indices were the same in each list, but don't have it quite right.

Comment: _The problem: If a correct username is entered, access is granted_ You have not shown us the code that grants or denies access.  We can't help unless you show us that code.

Comment: Your question appears to be about checking values, making comparisons and deciding whether or not user input is correct. But the code you share only defines some values and obtains two string inputs from the user. Please share the code you're actually asking about - we know it doesn't work, that's why you're asking, but StackOverflow is here to help you figure out why it is not working and how to fix it, not to write a new solution for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: General design advice: Keep related data together in a single object, like a dictionary, tuple, dataclass, or user-defined class. Separating the users and device IDs into different lists just makes things harder. Use a list of tuples, for instance.

Comment: `device in device_id` will never be true, because `device` is a string but `device_id` contains integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking whether the pair is in the valid pairs:

```
if (user, int(device)) in zip(approved_users, device_id):
    print('access is granted')
```

Comment: I forgot all about zipping the lists together for a simple comparison, thank you for the help. It gives me some new ideas to try.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using parallel lists and indexes, try using dictionaries to look up the values for each user.

Example:

```py
# Create mapping of users to device id
users_ids = {
    'Chad': 127, 
    'Tina': 416, 
    'Jared': 709, 
    'Lars': 358, 
    'Henry': 672, 
    'Jasmine': 939
}

# Get input
user = input('Enter your username: ')
device = input('Enter your device id: ')

# Make sure user ID and device match
if users_ids.get(user) == device:
    print("You are good")
else:
    print("No match")
```

Comment: I forgot all about the dictionary version. I wasn't sure if you could append to a dictionary or not and that is why I used the lists. Great ideas here, I appreciate the help.